# JavaScript: p5.js Unknown Error

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I was just writing out my code and I save it to run it and its just not working anymore and I cant find the problem as I am quite noobish at this, I am using p5.js and here is my code:

```
var s;

function setup()
{
 createCanvas(700, 700);
 s = new Snake();
}

function draw()
{
  background(51);
  s.update();
  s.show();
}

function Snake()
{
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;

  this.xspeed = 1;
  this.yspeed = 0;

  this.update = function()
  {
    this.x = this.x + this.xspeed;
    this.y = this.y + this.yspeed;
  }

  this.show = function()
  {
    fill(255);
    rect(this.x, this.y, 10, 10);
  }

  this.direction(x, y)
  {
    this.xpeed = x;
    this.yspeed = y;
  }
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main().js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <style> body {padding: 0; margin: 0;} </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does your developer console say and what is your code supposed to do?

Comment: Is your JavaScript file actually named `main().js`? (If not, fix that.) But yes, the console in the browser is a tool you'll need to use a lot, so check to see what the error is there.

Comment: It's supposed to so far be only to display a black canvas and a white squar moving across it. Right now, I dont have access to the console.

Comment: Why is having my file name as main().js a problem, could you please explain>

Comment: What do you mean "I don't have access to the console." Do you need help learning how to open the console? If not, what is preventing you from looking at it?

Comment: It's fine if that's the actual name of your file. It's just a strange name, so I thought perhaps that isn't the actual name. (File names don't usually contain parentheses.)

Comment: I was using a live preview of my page in Atom, so I didn't have access, I had to run the code individually to read the console the error reads: TypeError: s is undefined. Also I name my files that so I have it easier to distinguish what files do what in my code.

Comment: You need to open up the [developer console](http://HappyCoding.io/tutorials/javascript/developer-tools) and see what errors are being shown. You should also really try to link to a CodePen or a JSFiddle running your code. What exactly do you mean when you say it isn't working? What do you expect this code to do? What does it do instead? Which line causes the problem?

Comment: @Presisor You *need* to find a workflow where you can see the console. It's the only debugging tool you have, so every time something breaks, you'll need to see the error message there.

Comment: Ok thanks, one guy posted an answer and my code works now, I'll take what you said and use from now on.

Answer (score 5):

`this.direction(x, y)` should be `this.direction = function(x, y)`

Running code below:

```js
var s;

function setup()
{
 createCanvas(700, 700);
 s = new Snake();
}

function draw()
{
  background(51);
  s.update();
  s.show();
}

function Snake()
{
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;

  this.xspeed = 1;
  this.yspeed = 0;

  this.update = function()
  {
    this.x = this.x + this.xspeed;
    this.y = this.y + this.yspeed;
  }

  this.show = function()
  {
    fill(255);
    rect(this.x, this.y, 10, 10);
  }

  this.direction = function(x, y)
  {
    this.xpeed = x;
    this.yspeed = y;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main().js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <style> body {padding: 0; margin: 0;} </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks it always seems like the small things get me.

Answer (score 1):

try changing the function `this.direction(x,y)` to `this.direction = function(x.y)`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to change this instruction `this.direction(x, y)` by  `this.direction = function(x, y)`